# Create a new console view each time I run my code in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

How can I configure Eclipse so that each time I run my Python code in Eclipse it creates a new console view that will only contains the code's output (and not the output of other currently running codes)? I use the PyDev perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there's such an option available... The console view (which is provided by Eclipse itself) actually hosts multiple consoles at the view, so, you should be able to pin a run and switch among the existing consoles, but Eclipse does not currently provide a way to create a new console view for each new console... (may be something nice to add to Eclipse itself, so, you can try creating a feature request at http://bugs.eclipse.org although it may take a good time to have that actually integrated unless the request comes with a patch).